# Is class parameters with the option type need not to pass a value?

Tags: scala, slick

this code:

```
class B(d:Int,val b:Option[Int])

object A extends App  {
  val c=new B(1)
}
```

is wrong at line `B(1)`, I have to give a value of `b`, like

```
new B(1,Some(2))
```

I am studying slick, the example code is:

```
final class MessageTable1(tag: Tag) extends Table[Message](tag, "message") {
```

class Table is in file main\scala\slick\relational\RelationalProfile.scala line 119:

```
abstract class Table[T](_tableTag: Tag, _schemaName: Option[String], _tableName: String) 
  extends AbstractTable[T](_tableTag, _schemaName, _tableName)
```

So the `_schemaName` have the type `Option[String]`, but when the example code create `Table`, it seems not pass a value to it, only give the other two parameters: `tag` and `"message"`, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Three lines down](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/relational/RelationalProfile.scala#L122), you can see that `Table` has an *auxiliary constructor* with two parameters of type `Tag` and `String` (note: no `Option` here):

```scala
def this(_tableTag: Tag, _tableName: String) = this(_tableTag, None, _tableName)
```

This is the constructor that is called in the example code you showed, not the primary constructor.

You can also see the two constructors in [the documentation](http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.1/api/index.html#slick.relational.RelationalTableComponent$Table@%3Cinit%3E(_tableTag:slick.lifted.Tag,_tableName:String):RelationalTableComponent.this.Table%5BT%5D).